# At what size of file seekg or tellg fails?

Tags: c++, windows, file, file-io, 64-bit

It's a well known method to determine the size of file:

```
// Open file and get file size
int FileSize;
std::fstream myFile;
myFile.open(myFileName, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
if (myFile.is_open())
{
    myFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    FileSize = myFile.tellg();
    myFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    myFile.close();
}
```

but I wonder at what conditions program fails?
What is the max file size supported in x32 and x64 windows?
when I on x32 can I use more than 2Gb files? and do I need to use int64 for FileSize?

**UPDATE:**

according to [this](http://www.firstobject.com/fseeki64-ftelli64-in-vc++.htm)

> The limit of signed 32-bit integer offsets in ftell and fseek is
>   2^31-1 = 2147483647 which is around 2GB.

Comment: The same for both, and depending on the filesystem, up to 2**64-1 bytes per file.

Comment: @Deduplicator when I on x32 can I use more than 2Gb files? and do I need to use int64?

Comment: "It's a well known method to determine the size of file" - replace `int FileSize` with `std::fstream::pos_type FileSize = 0;` and you may be on to something there. Right now `FileSize` is *indeterminate* if the file failed to open, overflow on-assignment if the file is larger than `INT_MAX`, or, yes, I suppose it could even actually *work*.

Comment: Note that the OS (x86 vs x64) has nothing to do with the max file size, that depends on the file system (FAT, FAT32, NTFS, etc.). [See here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938937.aspx) for some useful numbers.

Comment: @RogerRowland I'm asking about limits due to x32/x64 cases, not about OS limitations.